# How to get a result set containing the absence of a value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, distinct

Scenario: Have a table with four columns. District_Number, District_name, Data_Collection_Week, enrollments. Each week we get data, BUT sometimes we do not.
Task: My supervisor wants me to produce a query that will let us know, which districts did not submit a given week.
What I have tried is below, but I cannot get a NULL value on those that did not submit a week.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DistrictNumber, DistrictName, DataCollectionWeek
into #test4
FROM EDW_REQUESTS.INSTRUCTION_DELIVERY_ENROLLMENT_2021
order by DistrictNumber, DataCollectionWeek asc


select DISTINCT DataCollectionWeek
into #test5
from EDW_REQUESTS.INSTRUCTION_DELIVERY_ENROLLMENT_2021
order by DataCollectionWeek


select b.DistrictNumber, b.DistrictName, b.DataCollectionWeek
from #test5 a left outer join #test4 b on (a.DataCollectionWeek = b.DataCollectionWeek)
order by b.DistrictNumber, b.DataCollectionWeek asc
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option uses a `cross join` of two `select distinct` subqueries to generate all possible combinations of districts and weeks, and then `not exists` to identify those that are not available in the table:

```
select d.districtnumber, w.datacollectionweek
from (select distinct districtnumber from edw_requests.instruction_delivery_enrollment_2021) d
cross join (select distinct datacollectionweek from edw_requests.instruction_delivery_enrollment_2021) w
where not exists (
    select 1
    from edw_requests.instruction_delivery_enrollment_2021 i
    where i.districtnumber = d.districtnumber and i.datacollectionweek = w.datacollectionweek
)
```

This would be simpler (and much more efficient) if you had referential tables to store the districts and weeks: you would then use them directly instead of the `select distinct` subqueries.

Comment: @Hakka-4 If you are creating a table for each year, as implied by `instruction_delivery_enrollment_2021`, then this will unravel at the beginning of a new year/table since there will be no history in the table to provide the "missing" districts. You will need to either: (bad choice) get them from a prior year or (good choice), as GMB suggests, create a `Districts` table that provides all of the districts and, ideally, reference it from `instruction_delivery_enrollment_2021` (and subsequent years).